# Master's degree studies

Tags: graduate-admissions

I want to apply to a US/K university for masters's degree on economics/management. At the same time I have a Bachelor's degree in management and master's degree in economics. The problem is that my Bachelor's GPA on management is only 2.05, and master's GPA is 3.1/ Can I show my master's degree GPA when applying to master's degree, because most universities at least require 2.75 average on GPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most US institutions want copies of all of your higher ed transcripts. I don't know about UK. If asked for you should supply them.

But, also in the US, make other parts of the application convincing about your likelihood of success. Letters of Recommendation, for example.